# Encrypting .txt File Erroring - Process Cannot Access File

Tags: vb.net, encryption, file-access

I'm trying to encrypt a `.txt` file which is created in my application.

To create this file, I'm using the following code:

```
Dim fileExists As Boolean = File.Exists(directorypath & "dbpw.txt")
If File.Exists(directorypath & "dbpw.txt") = False Then
   Using sw As New StreamWriter(File.Open(directorypath & "dbpw.txt", FileMode.Create))
         IIf(fileExists, "", "")
         sw.Close()
   End Using
End If
```

Then, to write and encrypt the file, I'm using the following code, calling subroutines that I tweaked from examples on the internet.

```
bytKey = CreateKey(txtCode.Text)
bytIV = CreateIV(txtCode.Text)

EncryptOrDecryptFile(directorypath & "dbpw.txt", directorypath & "dbpw.txt", bytKey, bytIV, CryptoAction.ActionEncrypt)
```

When the code gets to the final line, calling the `EncryptOrDecrypt` subroutine, an error is thrown saying

> The process cannot access the file 'myDirectoryPath\dbpw.txt' because it is being used by another process

What do I need to do to release the file?

I also tried just using `File.Create` along with `File.Encrypt` but the same error was thrown either way.

Code for `EncryptOrDecryptFile()`

```
Public Sub EncryptOrDecryptFile(ByVal strInputFile As String, ByVal strOutputFile As String, ByVal bytKey() As Byte, ByVal bytIV() As Byte, ByVal Direction As CryptoAction)

    Try
        fsInput = New System.IO.FileStream(strInputFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
        fsOutput = New System.IO.FileStream(strOutputFile, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write)
        fsOutput.SetLength(0)
        ' Currently fails, file not being released for read/write once it's created.

        Dim bytBuffer(4096) As Byte
        Dim lngBytesProcessed As Long = 0
        Dim lngFileLength As Long = fsInput.Length
        Dim intBytesInCurrentBlock As Integer
        Dim csCryptoStream As CryptoStream

        Dim cspRijndael As New System.Security.Cryptography.RijndaelManaged

        Select Case Direction
            Case CryptoAction.ActionEncrypt
                csCryptoStream = New CryptoStream(fsOutput, _
                cspRijndael.CreateEncryptor(bytKey, bytIV), _
                CryptoStreamMode.Write)

            Case CryptoAction.ActionDecrypt
                csCryptoStream = New CryptoStream(fsOutput, _
                cspRijndael.CreateDecryptor(bytKey, bytIV), _
                CryptoStreamMode.Write)
        End Select

        While lngBytesProcessed < lngFileLength
            intBytesInCurrentBlock = fsInput.Read(bytBuffer, 0, 4096)

            csCryptoStream.Write(bytBuffer, 0, intBytesInCurrentBlock)

            lngBytesProcessed = lngBytesProcessed + _
                                    CLng(intBytesInCurrentBlock)
        End While

        csCryptoStream.Close()
        fsInput.Close()
        fsOutput.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
        errorLog(ex)

    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Calling `sw.Close()` is redundant since you wrapped it in a `Using/End Using` block. As for your issue the problem could be that the underlying stream isn't closed. Instead of `File.Open()` just pass the file name directly to the `StreamWriter`: `Using sw As New StreamWriter(directorypath & "dbpw.txt")`

Comment: @VisualVincent I didn't have `sw.Close()` originally, I only added it in to see if it resolved the issue. I changed the code as you suggested, to `Using sw As New StreamWriter(directorypath & "dbpw.txt", FileMode.Create)`, but it still throws the same error.

Comment: Not related to the issue, but `FileMode.Create` isn't valid in that context. Just remove that and keep the file name. The `StreamWriter` will create the file if it doesn't exist, and overwrite it if it does. -- Are you using/referencing this file elsewhere in your code?

Comment: Also, may I see the `EncryptOrDecryptFile()` method? It could be that you're trying to read from and write to the same file at the same time.

Comment: Other than the references I included in the example, the only place it's referenced is on the parent form - `If File.Exists(directoryPath & "dbpw.txt") = False Then`, and from here this subroutine is called. The `If` condition is needed on the parent form, which is why I've not removed it.

Comment: @VisualVincent I've added it into the question.

Comment: As I suspected... You're opening `fsInput` and `fsOutput` for the same file. Once you've opened `fsInput` it will restrict access to the file, which is why you cannot open `fsOutput` with write access. You'll either have to give the output file a different name _or_ keep an open encryption stream which you use every time you write data to the file.

Comment: @VisualVincent Yep, that's fixed it. I've now called the input file "dbpw-temp.txt" which gets deleted after the file is encrypted, just keeping the output file. Thanks.

Comment: Glad I could help! I'll write an answer so this can be marked as resolved!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Together with the parameters you pass it, in your `EncryptOrDecryptFile()` method you are trying to open two streams (`fsInput` and `fsOutput`) to the same file. Once you've opened `fsInput` it has exclusive access to the file, making `fsOutput` unable to open it for writing.

Your only options are:

- Rename either the input file or the output file so that the two streams open two different files, or:
- Keep a "global" encryption stream open to the file, which you use every time you want to write data to it.

**NOTE:** Someone in the future might suggest that you open `fsInput` with `FileShare.Write` in order to allow other processes to open the file for writing, thus also allowing the `fsOutput` stream to write to it as well. - **DON'T DO THAT!**

Allowing other processes to write to the file while you're reading from it can cause problems, even if it's your `fsOutput` stream. This is because you'll never be able to know *how much* data `fsOutput` is going to write. What if the encrypted data ***is longer*** than the original? That would result in it overwriting what `fsInput` is going to read next, thus corrupting the file.

Comment: Hi Vincent, whilst this did fix my issue, it has raised another one - I need to read the encrypted file and then pass the data into `EncryptOrDecryptFile()`. How can I read the data, store it into a variable, then get the correct value in `bytKey` and `bytIV` to use as the parameters?

Comment: @Harambe : Reading the data is done by `EncryptOrDecryptFile()`, isn't that enough? Why do you need to store the encrypted data in a variable? -- As for the key and IV they must be supplied by you (either by hardcoding it or by entering it in a `TextBox` like you do now). There's no way to get them from the encrypted data.

Comment: @Harambe : If you want to read the encrypted data into a variable you can get it via [**`File.ReadAllBytes()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readallbytes(v=vs.110).aspx), but you'll have to modify `EncryptOrDecryptFile()` to take a byte array as input instead and skip the `fsInput` stream.

Comment: I need to store the data in a variable as the encrypted data is the user-set database password. i.e. when running the setup, the administrator must choose the password, which is then stored in the file after encryption. I need to decrypt the password and store it in a variable for the connection string. Would something along the lines of `EncryptOrDecryptFile(File.ReadAllBytes(directorypath & "dbpw.txt"), directorypath & "dbpw-temp.txt"...)` do it? Then I can store the password in the temporary file, read it, then delete it?