# VB encryption XML Error 0x00 invalid

Tags: vb.net

I have been working on a password manager and I am having trouble with encrypting with rijndael as my padding is breaking and when I have fixed the padding errors I get left with Hexadecimals 0x00 left in the XML file at the end. When I try `csCryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock()` it removes too much and delete the ending element of my XML so i am not able to read the password data in.

Here is the encryption and Decryption Code

```
  '*************************
'** Create A Key
'*************************

Function CreateKey(ByVal strPassword As String) As Byte()
    'Convert strPassword to an array and store in chrData.
    Dim chrData() As Char = strPassword.ToCharArray
    'Use intLength to get strPassword size.
    Dim intLength As Integer = chrData.GetUpperBound(0)
    'Declare bytDataToHash and make it the same size as chrData.
    Dim bytDataToHash(intLength) As Byte

    'Use For Next to convert and store chrData into bytDataToHash.
    For i As Integer = 0 To chrData.GetUpperBound(0)
        bytDataToHash(i) = CByte(Asc(chrData(i)))
    Next

    'Declare what hash to use.
    Dim SHA512 As New System.Security.Cryptography.SHA512Managed
    'Declare bytResult, Hash bytDataToHash and store it in bytResult.
    Dim bytResult As Byte() = SHA512.ComputeHash(bytDataToHash)
    'Declare bytKey(31).  It will hold 256 bits.
    Dim bytKey(31) As Byte

    'Use For Next to put a specific size (256 bits) of 
    'bytResult into bytKey. The 0 To 31 will put the first 256 bits
    'of 512 bits into bytKey.
    For i As Integer = 0 To 31
        bytKey(i) = bytResult(i)
    Next

    Return bytKey 'Return the key.
End Function
'*************************
'** Create An IV
'*************************

Function CreateIV(ByVal strPassword As String) As Byte()
    'Convert strPassword to an array and store in chrData.
    Dim chrData() As Char = strPassword.ToCharArray
    'Use intLength to get strPassword size.
    Dim intLength As Integer = chrData.GetUpperBound(0)
    'Declare bytDataToHash and make it the same size as chrData.
    Dim bytDataToHash(intLength) As Byte

    'Use For Next to convert and store chrData into bytDataToHash.
    For i As Integer = 0 To chrData.GetUpperBound(0)
        bytDataToHash(i) = CByte(Asc(chrData(i)))
    Next

    'Declare what hash to use.
    Dim SHA512 As New System.Security.Cryptography.SHA512Managed
    'Declare bytResult, Hash bytDataToHash and store it in bytResult.
    Dim bytResult As Byte() = SHA512.ComputeHash(bytDataToHash)
    'Declare bytIV(15).  It will hold 128 bits.
    Dim bytIV(15) As Byte

    'Use For Next to put a specific size (128 bits) of bytResult into bytIV.
    'The 0 To 30 for bytKey used the first 256 bits of the hashed password.
    'The 32 To 47 will put the next 128 bits into bytIV.
    For i As Integer = 32 To 47
        bytIV(i - 32) = bytResult(i)
    Next

    Return bytIV 'Return the IV.
End Function
'****************************
'** Encrypt/Decrypt File
'****************************

Enum CryptoAction
    'Define the enumeration for CryptoAction.
    ActionEncrypt = 1
    ActionDecrypt = 2
End Enum
Sub EncryptOrDecryptFile(ByVal strInputFile As String,
                                 ByVal strOutputFile As String,
                                 ByVal bytKey() As Byte,
                                 ByVal bytIV() As Byte,
                                 ByVal Direction As CryptoAction)
    Try 'In case of errors.

        'Setup file streams to handle input and output.
        fsInput = New System.IO.FileStream(strInputFile, FileMode.Open,
                                           FileAccess.Read)
        fsOutput = New System.IO.FileStream(strOutputFile, FileMode.OpenOrCreate,
                                            FileAccess.Write)
        fsOutput.SetLength(0) 'make sure fsOutput is empty

        'Declare variables for encrypt/decrypt process.
        Dim bytBuffer(4096) As Byte 'holds a block of bytes for processing
        Dim lngBytesProcessed As Long = 0 'running count of bytes processed
        Dim lngFileLength As Long = fsInput.Length 'the input file's length
        Dim intBytesInCurrentBlock As Integer 'current bytes being processed
        Dim csCryptoStream As CryptoStream
        'Declare your CryptoServiceProvider.
        Dim cspRijndael As New System.Security.Cryptography.RijndaelManaged

        'Determine if encryption or decryption and setup CryptoStream.
        Select Case Direction
            Case CryptoAction.ActionEncrypt
                cspRijndael.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros
                csCryptoStream = New CryptoStream(fsOutput,
                cspRijndael.CreateEncryptor(bytKey, bytIV),
                CryptoStreamMode.Write)
                csCryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock()
            Case CryptoAction.ActionDecrypt
                cspRijndael.Padding = PaddingMode.None
                csCryptoStream = New CryptoStream(fsOutput,
                cspRijndael.CreateDecryptor(bytKey, bytIV),
                CryptoStreamMode.Write)
        End Select

        'Use While to loop until all of the file is processed.
        While lngBytesProcessed < lngFileLength
            'Read file with the input filestream.
            intBytesInCurrentBlock = fsInput.Read(bytBuffer, 0, 4096)
            'Write output file with the cryptostream.
            csCryptoStream.Write(bytBuffer, 0, intBytesInCurrentBlock)
            'Update lngBytesProcessed
            lngBytesProcessed = lngBytesProcessed + CLng(intBytesInCurrentBlock)
        End While
        'Close FileStreams and CryptoStream.

        csCryptoStream.Close()
        fsInput.Close()
        fsOutput.Close()
        'If encrypting then delete the original unencrypted file.
        If Direction = CryptoAction.ActionEncrypt Then
            Dim fileOriginal As New FileInfo(Application.StartupPath & User(intUserCount).strAccounts)
            fileOriginal.Delete()
        End If
        'If decrypting then delete the encrypted file.
        If Direction = CryptoAction.ActionDecrypt Then
            Dim fileEncrypted As New FileInfo(Application.StartupPath & "/Users/" & User(intUserCount).strUsername & ".encrypt")
            fileEncrypted.Delete()
        End If


        'Update the user when the file is done.
    Catch ex As Exception When Err.Number = 53 'if file not found
        MsgBox("Please check to make sure the path and filename" +
                " are correct and if the file exists." & ex.Message,
                 MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Invalid Path or Filename")
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: You might benefit from [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46039488/3740093). I made a wrapper around the `CryptoStream` that lets you create an encryptable or decryptable AES stream directly. All you need to do is hash the key yourself and the stream takes care of the rest (including the IV). The bonus is that using my example the decrypted file is loaded into memory, so you won't have it lying around in your file system.

Comment: that encryption method relies on rewriting data meaning the point of a XML would just be useless as i need to add and remove data and i can do the with your decryption but if i want to encryption again the data will/does not encrypt with the data the XML needs to work. i am just after a way to scan through a file and remove all hexadecimals that make the XML invalided. my padding is not working correctly and it is leaving the padding after the decryption but just removing the hexadecimals will be a lot easier then redoing the encryption. Also if you ask me to Flush() it not work.@VisualVincent

Comment: Please divide what you just said into more sentences. I barely understood the first thing you wrote. Specifically, _why_ doesn't/wouldn't my method work for you? It encrypts/decrypts a file just like yours. For the record you will always have to rewrite _the entire file_ when changing it, no matter which encryption method you use. You cannot encrypt only newly added data. -- As for padding, try PKCS7 and see if it makes a difference in your code.

Comment: Although, I just noticed that when decrypting you set `cspRijndael.Padding = PaddingMode.None`. You need to set the same padding when decrypting as when encrypting.

Comment: Yes however the stream doesnt close if i use the same padding @VisualVincent and sorry i ran out of characters when writing that

Comment: Wrap your streams in [**`Using` blocks**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/using-statement) (you always should for inline streams) and remove your own `Close()` calls. `Using` ensures that the streams are closed once they go out of its scope. You have to refactor your code and create some new variables so that you can initialize the `CryptoStream` outside the `Select Case` as well. -- By the way you still haven't answered my question: Why wouldn't my code work? It is functional and it is safer.

Comment: The code wouldnt work as it decrypts in to a variable thats a string however i need to read it from a xml so i can put it into a structured array meaning that rewriting data back and forth from a xml wont work @VisualVincent

Comment: But that's the thing: You can read and manipulate it in memory. XML is just a format. It doesn't matter if it's in a file or in memory. There's for instance [**`XmlDocument.LoadXml()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.loadxml(v=vs.110).aspx) which takes an XML-formatted string. And if you really want it in a file so badly all you have to do is to call [**`File.WriteAllBytes()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writeallbytes(v=vs.110).aspx) to write the decrypted data into one.